# Spring MVC 3: same @RequestMapping in different controllers, with centralised XML URL mapping (hybrid xml/annotations approach)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I like to keep all my mapping in the same place, so I use XML config:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">

    <property name="mappings">
        <value>
            /video/**=videoControllerr
            /blog/**=blogController
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If I create a second request mapping with the same name in a different controller,

```
@Controller
public class BlogController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String info(@RequestParam("t") String type) {
        // Stuff
    }
}

@Controller
public class VideoController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String info() {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler 'videoController' to URL path [/info]: There is already handler of type [class com.cyc.cycbiz.controller.BlogController] mapped.
```

Is there a way to use the same request mappings in different controllers?

I want to have 2 urls as:

```
/video/info.html

/blog/info.html
```

Using Spring MVC 3.1.1

**EDIT:**
I' not the only one:
https://spring.io/blog/2008/03/24/using-a-hybrid-annotations-xml-approach-for-request-mapping-in-spring-mvc

The rest of the app works perfectly.

Comment: I don't think so, because both these request mappings are processed by two different mapping handlers/adapters. Any way can you tell me the rational behind your decision to keep the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`?

Comment: Just a matter of personal taste. I like to have it centralized rather than defined in each controller. I think it offers more flexibility too.

Answer (score 5):

Just put a requestmapping at the level of the Controller also:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/video")
public class VideoController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String info() {
        // Stuff
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/blog")
public class BlogController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String info(@RequestParam("t") String type) {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, this, you can't play mix and match like that with XML and annotation based mappings.  They are handled by different mappers, not "summed together"

Comment: @Biju: That was what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Affe: you might be right, tho it makes sense to me. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use parameter per method mapping. See my question and answer:

- [@RequestMapping with "params" on same URL in different classes cause "IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler" in JUnit with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561691/requestmapping-with-params-on-same-url-in-different-classes-cause-illegalsta/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563228/173149